# How to override CSS selector?

Tags: css

My page includes a legacy css file which defines a style for the `:invalid` psuedo-class. I want to use some of the styles from this file, but I do not want `invalid` inputs to be red by default, I want input fields to use the default styling for input fields defined in the legacy file.

legacy.css

```
input:invalid {
  background-color: #F00
}
```

Is there a way to override the style defined in legacy.css, and force it to use some other style from the file? Is there a better option for approaching this?

my.css

```
input:invalid {
  // super input:valid
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your CSS is loaded after the legacy one, it will take priority, otherwise, just add !important to your style

```
input:invalid {
  background-color: #FF00 !important
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried, the **initial** value for background-color to set background's color to default value ?

```
input:invalid{
    background-color: initial;
}
```

If the css file "legacy.css" have some style for this selector, they are not modified normally

Answer (score 0):

Use `!important;` in `legacy.css` to override the selector in `my.css`.

**OR**

Make your selector  in `my.css` more specific so that it has greater weight over the selector in `legacy.css`. This is called specificity. More about this [here](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`intitial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial) for the property value.

> The initial CSS keyword applies the initial value of a property to an element.

Just make sure your selector appears **after** the original selector.

```css
input:invalid {
  background-color: #F00
}

input:invalid {
  background-color: initial;
}
```

```html
<input type="email" name="email" required>
```

When using `!important` you artificially increase the properties weight (not exactly specificity, but similar). I would avoid using `!important` as it is *typically* bad practice and not required here.